# Do you need python to use casper.js ? if so why?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, casperjs

I never use python. The only language I know is JavaScript. I use node to do web work and I kept reading about how casper.js can scrape webpages. so I was thinking I could use it like usual. Now I am at the point of installing it and I get `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I know this means to put python on my path. I don't want to install python.

I use JavaScript why should I install python? I'm just confused that since `casper.js` has a `js` at the end I would think that it would rely on `js` and not python. so can you confirm if I really need to install python. I really don't want to deal with another language right now. Is it a simple process?

Comment: I'm not a node.js user, but one thing is clear: [casper.js won't work in node.js](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-casperjs-a-node-js-library).

Comment: I installed phantom. so I should be good  if I add Python to path? I could use phantom with node I think. phantomjs works for me, I tested it with a simple console. it's the python error that I'm up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, casper.js requires Python:  http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html

> PhantomJS 1.9.1 or greater. Please read the installation instructions for PhantomJS
>
> Python 2.6 or greater for casperjs in the bin/ directory

However, all your *coding* will be in JavaScript. You don't have to (and, in fact, cannot) write a CasperJS script in Python.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you need python to use casper.js?

Yes.

> If so, why?

CasperJS requires python because its devs chose to use python for [its executable entrypoint and internal test runner](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/search?l=python).

There is [discussion](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1524) around removing the python dependency for the 2.0 release (shell scripts and node.js have both been proposed).

---

Also, just for clarity: CasperJS *does not use node.js*. The fact that node requires python is irrelevant. CasperJS is an interface to PhantomJS, which is a headless webkit driver that happens to be scriptable by javascript, but is not built on node.js.

From the Casper docs:

> While CasperJS is installable via npm, it is not a node.js module and will not work with NodeJS out of the box. **You cannot load casper by using require(‘casperjs’) in node.**

Comment: "You cannot load casper by using require(‘casperjs’) in node." ? Goto casperjs official website ( http://casperjs.org/) and take a look at the sample program , casperjs is loaded with  require(‘casperjs’) . Could you explain what is meant here?